# Dodging geom_line() with a factor other than the group aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to make a figure with dodged geom_line(), but I need to dodge it using a factor that is not the same as the aes(group) factor.

Here's a walk-through of my issue.

First, generating some data:

```
require(tidyverse)

treatment <- c(rep("t1", 15),
               rep("t2", 15))
sample <- c(rep("a", 5),
            rep("b", 5),
            rep("c", 5),
            rep("d", 5),
            rep("e", 5),
            rep("f", 5))

depth <- rep(1:5, 6)
set.seed(112)
values <- rnorm(30)
df <- tibble(treatment, sample, depth, values)
```

Initial plotting of the data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = depth, y = values, color = treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

This generates a plot with nonsensical lines:
[image]

So, I specify a `group` aesthetic to use:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = depth, y = values, color = treatment)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = sample))
```

This generates a better figure.
[image]

However, my real-world case contains a lot more data, and treatments overlap. I wish to dodge treatments to better display each treatment's values:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = depth, y = values, color = treatment)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

[image]
This dodges `geom_point()` based on the previously specified `color` aesthetic, but dodges `geom_line()` using its `group` aesthetic, which is already set as `group = sample`.

Essentially, the issue is that `position_dodge()` appears to preferentially use the `group` aesthetic, and I have found no way to dodge the lines without changing to `geom_path()`. This allows me to not specify a `group` aesthetic to get to the second figure, but I prefer not using as it requires the data frame to be perfectly in order (and I have not managed to make it function using my real-world dataset).

Any `geom_line()` solutions out there?

Comment: If you specify `aes(group = sample)` in `geom_point` as well, that should do the trick.

Comment: @user727089, while that dodges both points and lines based on the same variable, it dodges them both based on ```sample``` (6 groups) instead of ```treatment``` (2 groups).

Answer (score 0):

Let each `color` be its own `geom_path` layer, and manually `position_nudge` each of those `geom_path` layers to match up with the `position_dodge` of the `geom_point` layer.

[image]

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(112)
DODGE_WIDTH <- .5

treatment <- c(rep("t1", 15), rep("t2", 15))
sample <- c(
  rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 5), rep("d", 5), rep("e", 5), rep("f", 5))
depth <- rep(1:5, 6)

values <- rnorm(30)
tb <- tibble(treatment, sample, depth, values)

ggplot(tb, aes(x=depth, y=values, color=treatment)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=DODGE_WIDTH)) +
  geom_line(
    data=filter(tb, treatment=="t1"),
    aes(group=sample), position=position_nudge(x=-DODGE_WIDTH/4)) +
  geom_line(
    data=filter(tb, treatment=="t2"),
    aes(group=sample), position=position_nudge(x=DODGE_WIDTH/4))
```